# Evaluation of decorator argument cause NameError

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator that takes one argument:

```
def supportSlice(ret_type=None):
    ...
```

and I want to apply it to a member function of a class, with the class itself as the argument:

```
class BitArray:
    @supportSlice(ret_type=BitArray)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        ...
```

But I got an NameError when evaluating `@supportSlice(ret_type=BitArray)` said "name 'BitArray' is not defined". It seems like the decorator isn't evaluated in the environment I expected.

My question is when exactly a decorator of a member function is evaluated? And also is there any walk-around to achieve the goal I described above?

Answer (score 3):

At the time the decorator runs (inside `class BitArray`'s body), the name `BitArray` is not defined yet!  A class's name gets defined **after** its body is done and its metaclass (usually `type`) builds the class object.

The simplest work-around is to delay the determination of `ret_type` to later...:

```
def supportSlice(ret_type=None):
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapfunc(self, *a, **k):
          if ret_type is None:
              rt = type(self)
          else:
              rt = ret_type
          # rest here, using rt
        return wrapfunc
    return wrapper
```

(it's simpler of course if you don't need to force a `ret_type` different from `type(self)` so you can use an arg-less decorator and thereby lose one level of function nesting:).

Comment: Thank, that is what i'm doing now.